# How to count number of lines after a certain line

Tags: python

I am trying to write a code that will count number of lines after *certain* line. I would like to compute all the lines that appear in my file after {A   B} appearing in my file

```
{A   B}
1     1
0.072 108.815
0.217 108.815
0.362 108.814
```

My code is as follows:

```
from __future__ import with_statement
def file_len(fname):
   with open(fname) as f:
        for i, l in enumerate(f):
             pass
   return i + 1

t=file_len("test.ghx")
print t
```

I am not sure how I can modify this to count the number of lines after specific line that includes {A   B}.

Can anyone share some thoughts?

Comment: @user741592: This is quite a good way of counting the lines.  The usual convention is to use `_` as a variable name instead of `l`, so that you show that the actual line read is not used.  Sven's answer is very good, though, in my opinion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Skip the lines up to and including the line you are looking for, and count the remaining ones:

```
def file_len(fname):
    with open(fname) as f:
        for line in f:
            if line.strip() == "{A   B}":
                break
        return sum(1 for line in f)
```

Comment: +1, but `rstrip()` is probably really what you meant (instead of `strip`), no?

Comment: OP said "includes {A B}", so perhaps `if '{A B}' in line:` is the test he's after -- in that case, no strip necessary. Also, `len(list(f))` is IMHO more obvious than `sum(1 for line in f)` (though very slightly less efficient, as it has to create a list).

Comment: @EOL: Not really sure what's the exact logic the OP is looking for, but this certainly can be easily adapted.

Comment: @benhoyt:  `len(list(f))` would be fine as well if you don't mind to hold the whole file contents in memory.  But `sum(1 for x in iterable)` is a rather common idiom to extract the length of an iterable, so I think it's preferable here.

Comment: @Sven, ah yes, good call about memory usage for big files. I recant -- "just plain better" is better than "more obvious". :-)

Answer (score 1):

Count total number of lines in file, check in which line your tag appears, subtract from the total.